# Notify user when new record appears

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where a user can request something of another user. Using a model called `Request` it contains an `order` and the assigned `user` to which it applies.

What I would like to do is when the `user` receives a new `request` to notify them immediately, they should be able to accept or deny. Which is currently stored as a bool value in `Request.accepted` the default is nil.

This obviously requires back-end and front-end work. Have anybody done this or have experience with anything similar? Most ideal would be to display a bootstrap modal when a request appears, where they can accept or deny it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which version of rails you are using. More than one way is possible, also depends on the size of users and requests you are processing.

Add a `after_save` callback and call a mailers model
or add the request to a queue and run later a [1] `ActiveJob`

[1] http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html